# Galaxy S6 - Can't unlock phone after factory reset

Tags: samsung, locked-out, samsung-galaxy-s-6, accounts

I just got a new Galaxy S9 to replace my 3-year-old Galaxy S6 and I will be giving it to my mother so I did a Factory Reset to my Galaxy S6. To my surprise, doing a factory reset didn't actually delete everything from the phone so I went into recovery mode and did a "Wipe data/factory reset" from there.

After restarting the phone and connecting to a WiFi network I'm asked to enter my Samsung Account, which I did, but I can't get past this screen! When I click on the "Sign In" button this is what happens:

[image]

[image]

[image: description]

The dialogs disappear and nothing happens. If I put a wrong password it tells me the password is wrong but when entering the correct one I can't get past this. I tried doing a factory reset again, unlocking the device from my Samsung account (which fails because it says remote access is not enabled or something like that) and even removing the device from my Samsung account. I also tried multiple methods that you can find online to bypass this but none of them work on Android 7 (Nougat).

I don't know what else to do, my device is just unusable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got a solution to my problem, this is obviously a Samsung bug in their software because I can't unlock my phone with the legitimate Android account. The following method works for unlocking any Samsung phone which is good and, at the same time, bad because a skilled enough thief can unlock your phone (although he won't have access to the data because the phone must be wiped).

1. Download [Miracle Box](https://www.techeligible.com/2018/04/03/download-miracle-2-58-with-loader/), at this time 2.58 is the latest version.
2. Put your phone in Download Mode and connect it to the PC.
3. Open Miracle Box and go to the Samsung tab.
4. Select the `Reset Reactivation/EE Locks` and click `Start Button` and wait for it to finish.
5. Your phone won't boot now, download a stock Samsung ROM with the same version as you had. I had Nougat so I have to download that, don't try a lower version because the bootloader won't allow you to flash it.
6. Use ODIN to flash the new stock ROM.
7. You should be able to boot your phone normally without entering the Samsung account.

If you think this is too much for you give [UnlockJunky](https://www.unlockjunky.com/unlock/135308/622455) a try. It was going to be my last resource.